# Lipschitz continuity and slope

Tags: analysis

Lipschitz continuity is defined as follows: A function is Lipschitz continuous if there exists a $K \in \mathbb R$ such that

$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq K|x-y| \forall x,y \in D$

Now I was wondering if it is possible to say that if one function's Lipschitz constant is bigger than another function's, the first function's slope must also be bigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slope, or derivative, of a differentiable Lipschitz-continuous function is bounded, in absolute value, by the function's Lipschitz constant. Functions with a larger Lipschitz constant can thus have a bigger slope. There may, however, also be points in the domain at which a function with a smaller Lipschitz constant has a bigger slope.

Note that the Lipschitz constant is a *global* property of a function, whereas the slope is a *local* concept.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the maximally possible scope for a function with a bigger Lipschitz Constant over **its whole range** is bigger then for a function with a smaller constant (but that does not necessarily implies a bigger scope at each point, i.e. locally)?

Comment: That is right .